# I have to turn my Apple TV on to make it discoverable by laptops/phones

Tags: appletv, airplay, torrent

Whenever I want to share my screen to my apple tv, I first need to find the apple tv remote and turn it on.  I used to be able to, at anytime, go to the displays dropdown and select my Apple TV to share to.  Now, my ATV only shows up when I turn it on first.

I see the setting "sleep after X" on my ATV but I don't think this setting is the solution.

Is there a setting I'm missing?

My macbooks and iphone are all running the latest software, and no programs see it at all until I turn it on. ( itunes, beamer, display port, popcorn time )

Comment: People are voting for this question to close, but I think you just need to be more specific. By “cast” I assume you are referring to airplay. What OS X/iOS/hardware are you attempting to do so from? Are you attempting to do so through iTunes, or a third party client such as “Beamer”? Please provide specs on both ends.

Comment: I think some people have a difference of opinion on what is piracy and that might be causing some to view this as off topic here.

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, the "sleep after X" is the solution. If I can't see on my apple tv the power diode on - the device is at sleep and I will not be able to use it as a target for airplay.

It should be said my apple tv is only connected through wifi. I wonder if connecting it through ethernet would make any difference (although I suspect it wouldn't).